# How to find if a valid JSON string

Tags: pascal, lazarus

Hello guys Is there a way to know if a string is a valid JSON type string in lazarus.
I have been using GetJSON(testString)  but throws an error if string is not JSON type.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[`FPJSON.getJSON`](https://www.FreePascal.org/docs-html/current/fcl/fpjson/getjson.html) raises an exception if data does not contain a valid JSO in JSON.
Probably you do not want to *just* detect valid JSON (you do use the `getJSON` function), but want to continue further processing with correctly parsed data *if there is any*.
Therefore you can simply presume data *is valid* and rely on the exception should there be invalid data:

```pascal
program invalidJavaScriptObjectNotationDemo(input, output, stdErr);
    {$modeSwitch exceptions+}
    uses
        sysUtils, FPJSON, JSONParser;
    var
        JSO: tJSONData;
    begin
        try
            try
                JSO := getJSON('foo');
                { … continue doing other stuff with JSO … }
            finally
                JSO.free
            end
        except
            on status: exception do
                writeln(stdErr, 'An Exception occurred when parsing: ',
                                 status.message);
        end
    end.
```